# check file type from FileReference after file load complete

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Since using file extension to check file type is not reliable, I want to check file type from the raw data after upload file complete. Something like this:

```
var fr = new FileRerence();
fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoadComplete);

function fileLoadComplete(event){
    var rawData:ByteArray = event.target.data as ByteArray;
    getFileType(rawData);
}
```

Does it possible and if so, how to check file type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it manually by file signature. You need to read file signature from file raw data (usually first N byte) and compare it with expected file signature. Here is incomplete list of file signatures: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures. But if you want to use some specific file format, I am sure that you can find its signature.